# How to make a remote shell gui in java

Tags: java, ssh

I'm working on a java program that needs to be able to connect to a remote server and execute system commands. How would I create a command shell that looked exactly the same as windows command prompt for the client, but executes the commands on the remote server? Thx in advance

Comment: This is a java program presenting the user with shell access to a remote server?  Why not simply run ssh from a terminal outside the program?  It's hard to understand what's needed here.

Comment: It's part of a larger program, that's meant to have IT help out others remotely, I thought that shell access would be vital to this process

Comment: There are several good APIs freely available, something jshc comes to mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do, but it's not easy - java has never been great for command-line operation.  If you want to do it, look for java-based SSH implementations.

On the other hand, if the user will be running the java program from the command-line, it may be possible to execute an ssh command on the same terminal.

Here is a page that describes executing an external program from java: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1.